# UITableViewCell width on initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a custom UITableViewCell, that contains 2 labels. The one should have a fixed width, while the other one should expand to the right, as long as there is space.

I am creating the UILabels like this:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        codeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 20)]; 
        [self.contentView addSubview:codeLabel];
        [codeLabel release];

        nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(76, 4, self.frame.size.width - 100, 34)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];
        [nameLabel release]; 
    }

    return self;
}
```

The problem is that, at that point, `self.frame.size.width`, always returns 320.0, so the UILabels aren't sized properly. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Try self.contentview.frame.size..width

Comment: This is because of cellForRowAtIndexPath just creates a cell, without adding it to the table view, thus, it can't say, what width will it have. Later on, when this cell will be reused you can find out cell's width. Unfortunately, I don't know how to find out cell's width upon creation.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `autoresizingMask` of the second label to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`.

If your needs get more complicated than `autoresizingMask` can represent you'll need to implement your own `layoutSubviews`.